# Android update data if record exists

Tags: android

I have this code below which consist on my Android app DatabaseHelper Class, Currently i have hardcoded a row of data inside my database which is the `Barcode(263924)` and `Quantity(1)`.

But the problem is i'm currently trying to make it so that when the user adds the same barcode number i hardcoded into my database the quantity will +1 and not create a new row.

Sorry im currently new to android any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

MainActivity Codes

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String barcodes = result.getText();
    final String quantitys = "1";
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
    alert1.show();
    AddData(barcodes,quantitys);

}

public void AddData(String barcodes,String quantitys){
    boolean insertData = myDB.addData(barcodes,quantitys);

    if(insertData==true){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully Entered Data!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Something went wrong :(.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Database Code

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scan.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "scan_data";
    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "BARCODE";
    public static final String COL3 = "QUANTITY";
    public static final String COL4 = "TIMESTAMP";



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " BARCODE TEXT, QUANTITY TEXT, TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);

        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL2,263924);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL3,1);

        db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String code, String quant) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, code);

        String[] params = new String[]{code};
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL2 + " = ?", params);
        long result;
        if (data.getCount() > 0) {
            data.moveToFirst();
            String[] args = new String[]{data.getString(0)};
            contentValues.put(COL3, (Integer.parseInt(data.getString(2)) + Integer.parseInt(quant)));
            result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, COL1 + "=?", args);
        } else {
            contentValues.put(COL3, quant);
            result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        }
        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @KiranMalvi hardcoded a row of data in my database Barcode(263924) and Quantity(1) i want to make it so that when the user adds in a same barcode number the quantity will plus 1. else if its a different barcode number it will just insert

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

```
public boolean addData(String code, String quant) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, code);
    String[] params = new String[]{code};
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL2 + " = ?", params);
    long result;
    if (data.getCount() > 0) {
        data.moveToFirst();
        String[] args = new String[]{data.getString(0)};
        contentValues.put(COL3, (Integer.parseInt(data.getString(2)) + Integer.parseInt(quant)));
        result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, COL1 + "=?", args);
    } else {
        contentValues.put(COL3, quant);
        result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }
    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

For time stamp update use below code:

```
contentValues.put(COL4, " time('now') ");
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! But may i ask what if i want my timestamp to be updated as well when the user adds the same barcode?

Comment: i have updated my code pls take a look

Comment: My answer is working??

Comment: Yes it works but i have updated the code and have a new column `public static final String COL4 = "TIMESTAMP";` how do i make it so that it updates COL4 as well.

Comment: Check my updated answer: `contentValues.put(COL4, " time('now') ");`

Comment: I added that but it just print "time('now')" on my listview